# SqlException was unhandled by user code during execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-access

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here? The error shows that I have an error at `con.Open();`

Thanks in advance

```cs
public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\phonebook.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        con.Open();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into registration values('"+ firstname.Text +"', '"+ lastname.Text +"', '"+ email.Text +"', '"+ username.Text +"', '"+ password.Text +"', '"+ contact.Text +"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Write("<script>alert('record inserted successfully');</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have an InnerException property that tells you more about the problem.

Comment: You will need to see the message (and the inner exception's message if it is not null) to understand what the issue is, as is, we cannot quite say. As it has been pointed out, your code is prone to SQL Injection. Also, Ideally you open the connection, do your DB operations and close it. Opening a DB connection and leaving it open is usually not recommended.

Comment: Put a try/catch block around your method, that throws an error. Add a breaking point inside the catch and read that exceptions message. Also: responding with HTML/JS script ... well, there must be better ways ;)

Comment: Consider this code: `INSERT INTO registration VALUES ('" + firstname.Text + "');`. If `firstName.Text` contains `hello` then you get `"INSERT INTO registration VALUES ('hello');"`. If `firstName.Text` contains `abc'); DROP TABLE registration; -- ` then you get `"INSERT INTO registration VALUES ('abc'); DROP TABLE registration; --"` which is a perfectly valid SQL query and will insert the value before compliantly dropping the table. Use `SqlParameter` for parameters!

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: If you are getting the exception at the con.Open(); line, please check the connection string is correct. Also, attaching the Exception message will help others solve the problem quickly.